# Deploying a Quasar to Heroku fails

Tags: heroku, quasar-framework

I'm trying to push a Quasar app to Heroku and failing. The error seems to be:

```
remote: sh: 1: quasar: not found
```

I suspect my package.json is the issue:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,vue,scss,html,md,json}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "test": "mocha",
    "build": "quasar build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.16.1",
    "npm": "9.8.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
```

In my dev dependencies, I have:

```
"@quasar/app-vite": "^1.0.0",
```

And I've also set heroku config:set NPM_PRODUCTION=false

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide more context for that error? There should be some relevant lines immediately before it.

Comment: Do you have `@quasar/app-vite` installed locally? Does it appear in your `package-lock.json`, and is that file committed?

Comment: Thanks, I've installed it. New errors now.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Heroku [uses `npm ci` to install dependencies from your lockfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation). Make sure that you've installed `@quasar/app-vite` locally, and that it appears in your lockfile.

Then get rid of your `heroku-postbuild` script entirely. As noted above, Heroku will automatically install dependencies and [run your build script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) at build time. There's no need to re-run those commands.